# 2d list with a compact nested loop

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I've recently started learning python and have stumbled in a syntax dilemma. Is there a way to do what this pice of code does:

```
def crescentOrderArray1(rows, columns):
    arr = [[] for i in range(rows)]
    count = 1
    for row in range(rows):
        for colum in range(columns):
            arr[row].extend([count])
            count = count + 1
    return arr
```

with a discreet syntax like

```
def crescentOrderArray2(rows, columns):
    count = 1
    arr = [[count for i in range(rows)] for i in range(rows)]
    return arr
```

I've tried modifying the "count" statement in "crescentOrderArray2", but with no success. I was expecting a way iterate each time it adds a "count"

Comment: As an aside, `.extend([count])` should just be `.append(count)`

Comment: So, possibly with an assignment expression, but you should probably just stick to your for-loop. You *should not think of list comprehensions as an alternative syntax for for-loops*. List comprehensions are for **mapping filtering operations that create lists**. In this specific case, you can express it that way, as shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it's the most compact way:

```
def crescent_order_array(rows, columns):
    return [[i+j for i in range(1, columns+1)] for j in range(0, rows*columns, columns)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 range objects. One iterates the start count for each row and the other expands into its column values.

```
def crescentOrderArray3(rows, columns):
    return [list(range(i, i+columns)) 
        for i in range(1, rows*columns+1, columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count` variable isn’t updated inside your list comprehension. Just use the values from the range generators:

```py
arr = [[row*cols+col for col in range(1, cols+1)] for row in range(rows)]
```

This will produce a 2D array of size `rows*cols`, with the top left value at zero and then incrementing by one each cell going right.

But there’s no real reason to do it in as few lines as possible. Write the code so it’s readable.

Comment: This is not quite correct as the values start at 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your `count` variable does not increment. Fortunately, you can just use the i and j values to calculate what count should be. See below output.

```
def crescentOrderArray1(rows, columns):
    arr = [[] for i in range(rows)]
    count = 1
    for row in range(rows):
        for colum in range(columns):
            arr[row].extend([count])
            count = count + 1
    return arr 

def crescentOrderArray2(rows, columns):
    arr = [[j+1 + cols*i for j in range(columns)] for i in range(rows)]
    return arr

rows,cols = (3,5)
print(crescentOrderArray1(rows,cols))
print(crescentOrderArray2(rows,cols))

>>>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
>>>[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in the code that you've written the `count` variable on the first line is different from the `count` variable on the second line.

The second line uses a local variable `count` within the list comprehension expression and this nested `count` shadows the one defined on the first line.

```
def crescentOrderArray2(rows, columns):
    count = 1
    arr = [[count for i in range(rows)] for i in range(rows)]
    return arr
```

One possible way you can rewrite your code into a more idiomatic form is to use list comprehensions and a helper function `chunks` that splits a list into equally sized chunks:

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]


def crescentOrderArray2(rows, columns):
    return [list(x) for x in chunks(range(1, rows*columns), columns)]
```